# How is stem length (reach) measured?

Tags: parts, stem, geometry

How is the length of a stem measured? Where does the measurement start and finish?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds as though you are talking about what [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_st-z.html#stem) term "reach", which is

> normally measured center-to-center along the direction of the extension

So this does not take into account the angle of the stem, which could reduce the length forward that the handlebars extend by a small amount if they are on a large angle up or down.

[image]

Comment: http://www.habcycles.com/stemfit.jpg - Edit this into your post.

Comment: http://www.brightspoke.com/t/bike-stem-calculator.html I've used this to estimate how much rise one would achieve as well.

Comment: @domsterr - thanks for the link - I did see that one but I was looking for something a little bit more specific to just how you take the measurement without the extra info.  I added it anyways until I can find or make another.

Comment: @AnthonyK 1. You answered "reach" but later on you described "extension" 2. The answer should be "extension". A "110mm stem" is a stem with 110mm extension, not 110mm reach